# Mounting NFS issues - LVM - ext4

Tags: mount, ext4, nfs

I set my ubuntu desktop up with LVM2. I don't know if that is contributing to the issue or whether I have forgotten something.

When I try to mount the external filesystem with this command:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 192.168.1.2:/media/backup/sorted /home/stuart/home-nfs
```

over the network I get the following ouput:

```
mount: special device 192.168.1.2:/media/backup/sorted does not exist
stuart@stu-hp:~$ edit test.txt
```

However, running the following code works, so I know that it is 'there'.

```
stuart@stu-hp:~$ scp test.txt 192.168.1.2:/media/backup/sorted
stuart@192.168.1.2's password: 
test.txt                                      100%   11     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

My `/etc/exports` file on the nfs (Centos 6) server looks like so:

```
/media/backup/sorted 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

I get the following output when I manually stop and start the nfs service:

```
[root@tower backup]# service nfs stop

Shutting down NFS daemon:                                  [  OK  ]
Shutting down NFS mountd:                                  [  OK  ]
Shutting down NFS quotas:                                  [  OK  ]
Shutting down NFS services:                                [  OK  ]
[root@tower backup]# service nfs start
Starting NFS services:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting NFS quotas:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS mountd:                                       [  OK  ]
Stopping RPC idmapd:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting RPC idmapd:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS daemon:                                       [  OK  ]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get a block device on the client using NFS, so you don't mount a filesystem remotely using NFS, instead you mount it as *NFS*. At the client it's of no interest what the actual file system is on the NFS server. Similar to how SCP, FTP and CIFS also doesn't care - it's on a different level.

So, the

```
sudo mount -t ext4
```

becomes

```
sudo mount -t nfs
```

For Ubuntu, you'll need the `nfs-common` package to be able to have the `nfs` type of mount available.

Comment: After doing that and running `sudo apt-get install nfs-common` on client it now works thanks!